# Why is there a difference between heap dump and live heap size?

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am trying to find analyze the heap memory for my application using `sudo watch -d -n1 jstat -gc 2342` it shows as **4GB heap size**:

```
S0C     S1C     S0U     S1U   EC        EU       OC          OU        
18432.0 17920.0 7736.5  0.0   1711104.0 638785.9 3495424.0   831624.7

MC       MU       CCSC    CCSU     YGC   YGCT      FGC   FGCT    GCT  
447616.0 185520.7 80512.0 23790.2  67039 2248.559  62    111.219 2359.778
```

But when I took a heap dump using the command
`jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=/tmp/dump.hprof 12587`, I see the size of the dump as **less than a GB**. Any reason why this could happen?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I tried to prettify your question...

Comment: IIRC The difference is between how much space is *available* and how much is *actually being used*. The rest of the 4GB are for the program to expand into, should it need the memory. It also probably overlaps with the allocated heaps of other programs running on your system.

Comment: Not an expert on Java Heap and heap dumps, but maybe the 4GB contains dead objects that are still waiting for GC? Your jmap dump explicitly excludes those (`-dump:live`), so maybe that's the reason?